# what is the fastest way to copy and ROS topic to another ROs topic based on some condition without having a node in between ? Is this possible?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

what is the fastest way to copy and ROS topic to another ROs topic based on some condition without having a node in between ? Is this possible ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/307871/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-copy-and-ros-topic-to-another-ros-topic-based-on-some-condition-without-having-a-node-in-between-?-is-this-possible-?/) by [jithinreju@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/37550/jithinreju@gmail.com/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-11-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> what is the fastest way to copy and ROS topic to another ROs topic based on some condition without having a node in between ? Is this possible ?

*Copy*? No.

Clarification: not without a node in between, remember: ROS has no broker, so nodes are the only entities that participate in actual communication. No nodes `->` no communication.

*Redirect*: yes.

But only at system startup time (in ROS 1, see #q31718: I don't believe this has changed).

Use [remapping](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap).

See #q303611 for a high-level explanation.

---

Edit: if *copying* is really a requirement, you could take a look at the `relay` (and perhaps `relay_field`) nodes from the [topic_tools](http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools) package.

---

Edit 2: there is a variant of `topic_tools` that has been implemented as a nodelet: [nodelet_topic_tools](http://wiki.ros.org/nodelet_topic_tools). It doesn't seem to provide a version of `relay`, but if it did, that would seem to be the closest you could get to zero-copy runtime rewiring/remapping of ROS topics in ROS 1.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-11-08**:
PS: I assumed 'fastest' to mean two things here:

1. most efficient
2. least amount of effort required on the developers side